# Finding Windows User in .net

Tags: .net

I am using Environment.UserName to get the UserName in .net , but Iam getting Machine name instead of UserName. Also I tried using 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
and even this returning Machine name instead of UserName.
Any idea?

Comment: Where are you calling this, Divya - on the client, or from within a server application to which a client is connecting?

Comment: Is something else in your code breaking the returned string in some way?  Are you sure it's not returning machine name _and_ user name?

Comment: If this is asp.net server side code, it's possible your in anonymous mode and your seeing the name IIS is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (found on http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4409/get-current-username-in-vbnet)

```
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
       "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
       ByRef nSize As Integer) As Integer

   Public Function GetUserName() As String
       Dim iReturn As Integer
       Dim userName As String
       userName = New String(CChar(" "), 50)
       iReturn = GetUserName(userName, 50)
       GetUserName = userName.Substring(0, userName.IndexOf(Chr(0)))
   End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. :)
I got it .Actually Iam trying to get the UserName in Dotnetnuke.
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username; solved my issue.
Thanks again.